# Does doing homework improve student's grades? (Statistical analysis)

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am currently measuring the progress on student's grades and their commitment in doing their homework. **My goal here is to prove to them that doing homework will improve their grades.**

I am working with some dummy data so that I can change it as the semester goes by.

Here is the list of the students and their commitment in doing the homework (as stated before, as dummy data)

[image]

(the 1's are **homework done** as 0's **not done**).

Here are their grades

[image]

I have built the data intentionally to show that students that do their homework get better over time (hopefully that's what I will actually find)

**Important things**
- The measurement that I want is the **improvement** of the student's grades. That means that, if one of the students improved from 30% to 65% and he did all the homework, and another student did no homework and maintained his grades close to 70%, this statistical analysis should **still indicate** that doing homework is highly favorable to improving grades (even considering that 70% is higher than 65%)

**My question**
Which type of statistical analysis should I use for this? Can someone shine a light in a good direction?

**Link to the spreadsheet (just in case)**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bcEkJzf-jacxz0TOcC9dUC2jnmMLiakXC292ytwEcKA/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Group 1 is students who claim commitment to doing hwk, Group 1 is students who don't. Within each group, find  _improvement scores_ (differences). Then do a two-sample test to compare the two groups. If you believe differences are roughly normal, the test should be a Welch (separate-variances) t test. If differences are extremely skewed or if there are extreme outliers, then use Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon nonparametric two-sample test ("rank-sum test").

Comment: You're hoping to prove to them that doing homework improves their grades over the course of the semester, but you won't have the real data for this until the end of the semester.  So are you going to prove this with fake data, or prove it at the end of the semester when it's too late to do them any good in this course?

Comment: And what are you going to do if it turns out that the students who do homework don't improve?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes I am building the model/study before getting the real data (i.e. proving with this fake data). I don't see the problem in doing so. And, if doing homework doesn't improve their grades, the analysis will show exactly that, and that's it. However, I strongly doubt that it will happen.